# mysql: I want to sum up all the values of credit from table semester and then add to another column total_credit from another table

Tags: mysql, view, left-join

I have the below code:

```
UPDATE VIEW
LEFT JOIN sem_view ON (view.semester = sem_view.semester)
SET view.t_credit = SUM(sem_view.credit)
```

but its not working saying invalid use of group

Comment: Given that the sum is derived data, I recommend _against_ doing this update.  Use a query or view instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Data for updating must be perpared previously, in subquery. Updating must use the data which is already aggregated.
2. Left joining may be errorneous - it will set the value in the destination table to NULL if according data for the semester in interest in `sem_view` is not present. But if the logic needs this then you may use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER one in the below query.

Totally:

```sql
UPDATE `view`
JOIN ( SELECT sem_view.semester, SUM(sem_view.credit) summ
       FROM sem_view 
       GROUP BY sem_view.semester ) data_for_updating
                                    ON `view`.semester = data_for_updating.semester
SET `view`.t_credit = data_for_updating.summ;
```

PS. The text looks like `view` is a name of a table to be updated.

Comment: Probably not a good idea given that the sum is derived data.  Just use a view instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is true primarily - but the situations may differ... an example - `view` is a static snapshot table which may be edited later, i.e. its final state values must not match the statistic from the base table.